# I having the two json response from the server side with the same "key".The json is posted below

Tags: android, json, retrofit2, gson

```
    {"data":
         {
          "userId":"+919923911289",
          "inTime":"2016-07-25 12:09:47+05:30",
          "outTime":"0",
          "totalTime":"0",
          "type":"attendance"
          }
}
```

> And the second json response is

```
{"data":"please try again..."}
```

> I am using retrofit to get the response . For the first json i have created the Gson model.But , when the response is in the second json format i didn't have any response model for it.

I am displaying the data using the GsonModel for the first json response.
And if there is second type of response what should i do here.Will i use the TypeToken here or something else.

And it also giving me the parsing exception wich i understand.But , i didn't know what i have to do.

Comment: do you get the second response in case of error ?

Comment: When I'm posting the correct mobile no. I will get the first response and if the mobile no is not correct or it is not matched with my database entry it will give me the second response.

Answer (score 2):

Create a another model

```
class ErrorModel{
     String data;
}
```

and in your main method:

```
try{
    GsonModel model = gson.fromJson(response,GsonModel.class);
    // ...
}catch(JsonSyntaxException e){
    ErrorModel model = gson.fromJson(response,ErrorModel.class);
    // show error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(data.has("userId") && !data.isNull("userId") ){
    String user_Id=data.getString("userId");
}else{
 ////show message "please try again..." here....
}
```

Comment: Some explanation about why this code works would be useful

Answer (score 0):

```
if (data.equalsIgnoreCase("please try again...") {
    //show error
} else {
    //do your work with response
}
```