# How to get the retrofit response in string format ? And convert that response into the model?

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit2

I am having the  json in the response.But, i want it into a string format.And i want to convert that string response into a model.Because, in the json response data the value may get changed.

So, How to get the response into the string format using the retrofit2 ?
And how to use TypeToken to convert it into a respective model?

Comment: please don't post the same question over and over

Comment: @Blackbelt sir  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38561876/i-having-the-two-json-response-from-the-server-side-with-the-same-key-the-json

Comment: But @Blackbelt sir there i'm getting the response in the Model format.And i want the response in the string format.That's why i asked this question.